# l3doc: conditionally include debugging code between macrocodes

Tags: spacing, l3doc

My `package.dtx` exports `package.sty` and `package-debug.sty`, which contains more material that is not typeset in `package.pdf`. To achieve this I use the following pattern where the package name is `package-debug` when the `nodebug` export flag is false, and `package` when the `debug` export flag is false. The `gobble` environment gobbles lines that should not appear in `package.pdf`.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \NewDocumentEnvironment {gobble} { +b } {} {}
%    \begin{gobble}
%<*package>
%    \end{gobble}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/01/01]
\ProvidesExplPackage
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{gobble}
%<*!debug>
% \end{gobble}
%    \begin{macrocode}
  {package}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{gobble}
%</!debug>
%<*!nodebug>
  {package-debug}
%</!nodebug>
% \end{gobble}
%    \begin{macrocode}
  {2022/10/28}
  {1.0}
  {Minimal example}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{gobble}
%</package>
%    \end{gobble}
```

The output reads

[image]

How can I remove the extra vertical space before and after line 3 ?

I tried something like

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment {gobble} { +b } {\vspace{-0.5em}} {}
```

but in practice the `-0.5em` length is sometimes too big, sometimes too small.

Answer (score 1):

this has nothing to do with your debug and gobble code. You get this space also simply with two macrocode environments. macrocode uses trivlist, and so the easiest is to use enumitem and to set the `nosep` option:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[trivlist]{nosep}


\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \NewDocumentEnvironment {gobble} { +b } {} {}
%    \begin{gobble}
%<*package>
%    \end{gobble}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/01/01]
\ProvidesExplPackage
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{gobble}
%<*!debug>
% \end{gobble}
%    \begin{macrocode}
  {package}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{gobble}
%</!debug>
%<*!nodebug>
  {package-debug}
%</!nodebug>
% \end{gobble}
%    \begin{macrocode}
  {2022/10/28}
  {1.0}
  {Minimal example}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{gobble}
%</package>
%    \end{gobble}
```

[image]

Comment: This also removes the vertical space before and after each macrocode environment, which is undesirable. I only want to remove the vertical space between consecutive macrocode environments. On solution is to use a surrounding environment to manage vertical space, but is is highly verbose.